# Does Lord Indra protect the Aryan, Vedic civilization from attacks by Mleccha armies?

Tags: indra, war, arya, mleccha

It is said in the Vedas that Lord Indra is the Kshatriya of the Devas. So, he functions like a king and protects Earth and Swarga, and fights offenders.

Does Lord Indra protect the Aryan, Vedic civilization from attacks by Mleccha armies?

For example, it is said in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33346/are-there-yajnas-in-the-vedas-for-destroying-the-civilizations-of-the-mlecchas) that there mantras in the Rig Veda which talk about such things.

But is there any verse in the Vedas that explicitly says the Devas protect the Vedic civilization from Mleccha aggressors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there any verse in the Vedas that explicitly says the Devas protect the Vedic civilization from Mleccha aggressors?

**Yes, it is the duty of Lord Indra to protect the Vedic civilization from attacks and destruction by the armies of the Mlecchas, Asuras, and Rakshasas.**

From the *Rig Veda Samhita*:

> [**3.34.9**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv03034.htm) He [Indra] gained possession of the Sun and Horses, Indra obtained the Cow who feedeth many.
>   Treasure of gold he won; **he smote the Dasyus [mlecchas], and gave protection to the Āryan colour.**

Here is another verse that talks about Indra launching his lightning bolt and destroying the military forts of the Mlecchas:

> **[1.103.3](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01103.htm)** Armed with his bolt and trusting in his prowess he wandered **shattering the forts of Dāsas [mlecchas].**
>   Cast thy dart, knowing, Thunderer, at the Dasyu; increase the Ārya's might and glory, Indra.

Another verse:

> **[1.104.2](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01104.htm)** These men have come to Indra for assistance: shall he not quickly come upon these pathways? **May the Gods quell the fury of the Dāsa, and may they lead our folk to happy fortune.**

Lord Indra is the personal recipient of the Yajnas performed by the Vedic Aryans, so he has a vested interest in making sure the Vedic civilization is guarded from destruction.

Comment: Why are Dasa and Dasyu translated/interpreted as mlechha? Is it correct to do so?

Comment: @Rickross Because they mean the same thing. Here is how the Rig Veda Samhita defines Dasyu: "Around us is the Dasyu , riteless, void of sense, inhuman, keeping alien laws. Baffle, thou Slayer of the foe, the weapon which this Dāsa wields." | It basically means foreigner / mleccha.

Comment: Dasyu basically means a rogue/dacoit/robber .. but why it is necessary that every foreigner will be like that? And, the usual meaning of Dasa is just servant

Comment: @Rickross The word has different meanings depending the context. Like in other places in the Rig Veda it means Asura. But in the verses I cited above, I think it means Mleccha. And I don't mean all foreigners are like that, just a generic statement about their civilization.

Comment: @Ikshvaku , Arent the ancient pagan greek/roman Zeus/Jupiter/Dionysus and his worshippers are the same as mlechha Dasyu, mentioned in Ridveda?